# Accessing Drawable resources from a non context class

Tags: android, resources, nullpointerexception, drawable

I'm defining a class that sets a Drawable attribute in an object. The problem is that I can't access the `getResource().getDrawable(int resourceId)` method unless I have some `Context`.
What I did was to send to that class an activity instance (let's call it "act") and then I did:

`act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whellchair)`

but, when executing that line it throws a `NullPointerException`.

When idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is "act" null or is "act.getResources()" null?

Comment: Hey mate! You just gave the critical hint! I didn't check what was null and turns out it was "act". I'm working with a singleton when put the line in the wrong place! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!
I'm using a singleton and I put the line accessing the "act" in a static method... how fool of me ...

Sorry and thank you Juhani for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass that the application context to the constructor of your class. In the main application class you just get the context by invoking the `getApplication()` method if you need the a lifetime aware context or `getApplicationContext()` if you need a the context which is tied to the current process.

Example:

```
private Context ctx = getApplication();

... some code ...

MyClass myClass = new MyClass(ctx);
```

Your classes' constructor of course has to handle the context accordingly (i.e. setting a private member of type Context to the passed value) like this.

```
private Context ctx = null;

public MyClass(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

Then you can use the context for whatever you need.

Comment: the class is a singleton (so it selfs instanciates) and it does not extends the class Activity to get access to getApplication() or getApplicationContext()

Comment: Well a class doesn't have to extend Activity in order to obtain the correct context (even if it would and call getApplication() it would get the wrong context most-likely as you want to display stuff and get a hold of stuff in the main activity most of the times). But apparently you've solved your problem anyway so alls good.